# How to prevent unnecessary copy of an object

Tags: c++

I have a rapidjson wrapper that does the following:

```
class ADocument
{
    void setJson(const char *data) { m_D.parse(data); }

    AData operator[](const char *key) const
    {
        const rapidjson::Value *value = rapidjson::Pointer(key).Get(m_D);

        if(value)
            return AData(value);
        else
            return AData(&m_D);
    }

private:
    rapidjson::Document m_D;
};
```

and the `AData` class like this:

```
class AData
{
public:
    Adata(const rapidjson::Value *val) : m_Value(val) {}

    operator QString() const { return m_Value.IsString() ? m_Value.GetString() : QString(); }

private:
    const rapidjson::Value *m_Value; 
};
```

And the whole thing is called like this:

```
ADocument doc;
doc.setJson("{\"Hello\":{\"Hello\":\"test\"}}");

QString str = doc["/Hello/Hello"];
```

when `str` becomes "test".

Now by debugging this code I found out that the `AData` object somehow shifts - the `operator QString()` gets called from an object in different memory location than the original `AData` object is constructed in the `operator[]` of `ADocument`. Regular constructor is called once. But it might be that copy-elision simply moved the same object around in memory.

However when I define one of *rule-of-three/five* methods such as a destructor in `AData` without changing anything else (and the destructor does nothing itself) then the `operator QString()` is called on the SAME OBJECT (same memory location) which got constructed in the `operator[]` of `ADocument`.

Even when I implemented all thinkable constructors and operators (move, copy, assign...) NONE of them is ever called but the result is the same - only one object is ever created.

What is going on here? I would like to understand it.

And further, how to change this implementation so that it is as performance and memory efficient as possible (=minimum copies etc.)? Or maybe I am really worrying about nothing here and what I am seeing is only some compiler optimization?

Comment: What's `AConstData`?

Comment: @AlanStokes Ah sorry, a typo. I copied the code from my source where I have actually two classes AData and AConstData. I used latter for some testing but they are both identical.

Comment: Sounds like copy elision is working as intended, what's the problem? I think you are worrying about nothing and should let the compiler do its job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is going on here? I would like to understand it.

You're experiencing *copy elision*.

When a unnamed temporary would be copied or moved into a variable of the same type, the compiler is allowed to construct the object directly in the variable and skip the copy or move operation.

Another situation where you may experience this is when you return a variable with automatic storage duration from a function.